# How do I get text in a pivot table in excel or google sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, google-query-language

I have a list of data, that I have cleaned, but I need to organize it in a way that allows me to import it into a CRM.

I can't think ov a way to convert that data into a decent table other than a pivot table.

The problem is the pivot table doesn't allow for just showing text.

Any way to do this?

Here is an example of the data

| [image]Column A | Column B |

Example Data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GgYA8FrqRd_1d2rONyANMQC0-BEcBAmLRa9CxjKLYc/edit#gid=0

I have tried xlookups, vlooks, all kinds of dumb things.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GgYA8FrqRd_1d2rONyANMQC0-BEcBAmLRa9CxjKLYc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({Data!A:A, Data!Q:S}, 
 "select Col4,max(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col4 
  pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", )
```

[image]

Comment: How did this work?  I can't figure out how to apply it to my other data set.

Comment: I just hit refresh a few times and it works lol  :-)  Still don't know how, but thank you!